# Will SSD swap improve performance?

Tags: performance, swap, ssd

I am wondering if i have only 4GB ram and somehow(virtualbox,browser) isn't enough and i cannot proceed to upgrade(due to ultrabook and soldered memory) will swap held in SSD help the overall performance??

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a hard disk in your notebook?

Comment: No i don't have HDD, it is a Dell XPS 13 Ultrabook and the ram is soldered as told in my question. Also the only available disk is the ssd included which is bound to m2 sata port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swap on SSD is going to be much faster than swap on a magnetic HDD. But it's still going to be pretty bad compared to having sufficient RAM.

Also, if you're thrashing to SSD, that's going to cause a lot of writes—it may wear out your SSD.

I'd suggest looking into zram and/or zswap to make your 4GB go further.

Comment: How about hdd with massive cache, or ram based ssd (usually battery backed, though you will have no need for the battery).

Comment: @richard you'd need a truly massive cache to matter. And yeah, one of the battery backed RAM cards typically used for databases would be fast, but I suspect it'd be cheaper to buy a new laptop. (And they're often PCI cards, which I doubt will fit in a ultrabook).